# Custom fields meta data not showing up in my widget

Tags: php, wordpress, metadata, widget, custom-post-type

Thanks to the help of others on this site, I now have my progress bar working fine on the page.

But every time I try to take that same source code and save it as a widget, it returns the data from my two custom fields - Target, and Complete - as zero.  Since Target and complete are the same, it shows all tasks complete in the widget.

here is the 'relevant' code snippet from the widget, I can post the full source if needed:

```
$challenge_widget_query = new WP_query( array( 'post_type' => 'challenges', 'posts_per_page' => 3 ) );

while ($challenge_widget_query->have_posts()) : $challenge_widget_query->the_post(); 

    echo "<li><a href='".get_permalink()."'>".get_the_title()."</a>";

$target = (int) get_post_meta($post->ID, 'target', true);             
$complete = (int) get_post_meta($post->ID, 'complete', true);       
$percentage = $complete / $target;
$percentage = round($percentage * 100);
$whatsleft = 100-$percentage;
if($whatsleft < 0) $whatsleft=0;

echo "<table width='250' border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'><tr>";

if($complete === $target) 
{echo "<td><img src='http://www.smokeyvstheworld.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/completed.gif' style='width:200px;height:24px;'></td>";}
elseif($complete == "0")
{echo "<td><img src='http://www.smokeyvstheworld.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/pending.gif' style='width:200px;height:24px;'></td>";}
else
{echo "<td width=". $percentage ."%><img src='http://www.smokeyvstheworld.com/wp-content/themes/spectre/images/brown/grnbar.jpg' style='width:100%;height:12px;'></td><td width=". $whatsleft ."%><img src='http://www.smokeyvstheworld.com/wp-content/themes/spectre/images/brown/grybar.jpg' style='width:100%;height:12px;'></td>";}


echo "</tr><tr><td colspan='2'><div align='right'>". $complete ." of ". $target ." completed</div></td>
  </tr></table></li>";

endwhile;
echo "</ul>";
```

This same source code on my page works fine...  I'm at a loss

you can see this working in both the page and widget at:
http://smokeyvstheworld.com/challenges

it seems to be cutting out what's in the echo"" at one point.  I guess I didn't format it to show well

Comment: Thanks for the edit.  Still confused why the loop is not returning meta data

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this to suss out where the actual problem is.

```
print "get_post_meta({$post->ID}, 'target', true)<br />";
print get_post_meta($post->ID, 'target', true);
```

This should give you something like

```
get_post_meta(12, 'target', true);
12000
```

If no number appears in the 12, you haven't added

```
global $post;
```

at the top, so it doesn't know what $post->ID is.

If the '12000' or another number doesn't appear, the 'target' meta key for that post hasn't actually been stored. You can check it by looking at your database in the **wp_postmeta** table.

Good luck!

Comment: THANK YOU!!  I actually had added  global $post; in the plugin, but it was at the very top, and not in the actual widget code, by moving it down to just above where I called the posts, everything was fixed!!